# MySQL select rank based on points field

Tags: mysql

I have a adapted a query I found to select the rank of stores based on a points field:

```
SELECT *,
IF (@score=ui.points, @rank:=@rank, @rank:=@rank+1) rank,
@score:=ui.points score
FROM stores ui,
(SELECT @score:=0, @rank:=0) r
ORDER BY points DESC
```

How can I modify this query to select the rank of an individual store, e.g. where stores.id = 2

Secondly, stores belong to an owner, an owner can have many stores.

Stores:

```
id, name, points, owner_id
```

Owners:

```
id, name
```

How can I then adapt the query to select the rank of an owner, based on the total score of their store points?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't.  For an individual score, just calculate the rank using SQL without variables.  Because you are doing a "row_number()" style count (where duplicate values get different ranks), the query is:

```
select count(*)
from stores s cross join
     (select s.* from stores s where s.id = 2) s2
where s.points > s2.points or (s.points = s2.points and s.id >= s2.id);
```

Comment: You've lost me on this - just returns 1?

Comment: This should return the count of stores with a higher score than `id =2`.